# How do I convert strings using GCI:unescape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, character

The string is:

```
"Hugo S%C3%A1nchez"
```

When I try to decode it it shows as:

```
irb(main):016:0> CGI.escapeHTML('Hugo S%C3%A1nchez')
=> "Hugo S%C3%A1nchez"
```

How should I make it work so it looks like `Hugo Sánchez`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CGI.unescape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescape):

```
CGI.unescape "Hugo S%C3%A1nchez" # => "Hugo S\u00E1nchez"
```